# Why was a vertical line added on the left for users who collapse the left navigation? Can it please be removed?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, design

I noticed that a vertical line has begun appearing on the left of every page in the new responsive layout, if I have the left navigation collapsed in my account settings. See screenshots:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Why was this vertical line added? I really don't like it there; can it please be removed? It's eye-catching and extremely distracting for me.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Can we hide the new line on the left of the page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372304/4642212)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier As a user with a mild case of autism spectrum disorder, I find it eye-catching and extremely distracting.

Comment: It wasn't just added for people who collapsed the left nav. It was moved completely from `border-right` on `#left-sidebar` over to `border-left` on `#content` in the style sheet. Everyone sees it whether they hid the sidebar or not.

Comment: Collapsing the left-sidebar? How does it even work?

Comment: @darijgrinberg You can choose that option in your user profile.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It's in your account settings. Unfortunately, logged-out users can't do it.

Comment: @TylerH: aaah, thank you!

Comment: The lines at the top of the page above "Your Answer" bother me too. It makes the site look boxed in.

Comment: @Zackary The line between question title and body? Hasn't that always been there?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog It apparrently has. But it looks a little thicker now.

Comment: this extra line looks extra ugly on sites with a light theme as there is this shift from the menu button when you scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pawel fixed this a few days ago. Now, if the left-nav is collapsed *and* the normal border for the content area is white, a gray border won't be shown on the left of the page.

Compare meta (white border):

[image: no border shown with nav collapsed on meta]

...With Unix & Linux (grey border):

[image: grey border shown with nav collapsed on U&L]

Comment: This same line seems to have sprung up again; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again