# Can the vertical line please be removed (again)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, regression

The same issue as [Why was a vertical line added on the left for users who collapse the left navigation? Can it please be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313930/why-was-a-vertical-line-added-on-the-left-for-users-who-collapse-the-left-naviga) has arisen again.

> [image]
>
> [image]

The bug was initially fixed, but it seems to have regressed. I'm posting again because SE generally prefers we file new bug reports if a fixed bug comes up again, rather than removing the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag on the older one.

Again, I really don't like it there. It's eye-catching and extremely distracting for me.

Comment: looks like a wiedergänger ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh, 100%. And I promise this'll come back even after I fix it this time :)

Comment: it looks like, that is it still there ...

Comment: It's fixed now lol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of the themes implementation details are still firming up, and this is a regression I introduced... again :)

Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: When will this be rolled out?

Comment: The change hasn't been made yet, so when I'm able to get it. I'm done for the day today.

Comment: Okay, then have a great day!

Comment: It's coming back again.

Comment: I think this problem is also related. See: [Why do I have empty space on the left suddenly?
](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314887/why-do-i-have-empty-space-on-the-left-suddenly)

Comment: For those who use Stylus or similar: Create a style using this: `#content { border-left-width: 0; }`

Comment: @mrt It's not until now that I know that *Stylish* is banned universally... I decide to modify it on my own since they don't make a change at all.

Comment: Hey Aaron, mind marking [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373392/2288578) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373469/2288578) as [meta-tag:status-completed]? Cheers.

Comment: It's back Aaron! On meta.so this time.

Comment: @Clonkex The line is intentional to contrast the background with the foreground content. There's also a line on the right. Both are intentional.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's still a line on my screen but the margin is noticeably reduced compared to [@Rick's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314887/why-do-i-have-empty-space-on-the-left-suddenly). Note where the home button is positioned on my topbar, they're much nearer to the left. I believe the two problems are related but Sonic's request is a separate issue. Unfortunately, I cannot post an "answer" there because it is closed as a duplicate.

> [image]