# Why do I have empty space on the left suddenly?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I didn't have the empty space early this day. What happened? I've already 
ticked "hide side bar...".

Can I remove it again with settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see an empty space on the lefthand side here as well?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've uploaded another pic. I seldom visit meta here. So I don't know if  it's acting normally. Do you have the empty space on SO too, or is it only me?

Comment: Nope. No empty sidebar for me, and I have switched off sidebar thingy. This looks like a bug. Have you refreshed your page by the way? Cleared the cache sort of thing. Sorry, but I'm not a techie.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How could you not have this UI too...? I've cleared the cache, tried with Firefox, still the same.

Comment: I would go sleep and see how it becomes tomorrow.

Comment: I would stay up for a bit more and answer any questions that may be posted in the comments. And I would tag your question "bug" that will get the devs' attention. And I would say which operating system you're running and if this is reproducible on Chrome, IE, etc.

Comment: Is this related to [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again)? I can also see a thin vertical line but the space delimited  is narrower than in your screenshot.

Comment: Per OP's chat message [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7195840#7195840), the vertical line just created the illusion of extra space, so this is the same issue as [Can the vertical line please be removed (again)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog objectively speaking, the space in the second screenshot looks massive. Note how much space there is before the home button. On my desktop, the home button is much closer to the edge. And now that I'm looking, the buttons on the first screenshot are further to the right

Comment: @Mari-LouA In that case, you should probably file a new [tag:feature-request] to have the space reduced. I personally like the space because it makes the post column size shorter and thus makes posts more readable.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog but the space margin on my screen *is* reduced compared to Rick's.  Look at the left side buttons on Rick's topbar there's a sizable margin, on mine there isn't.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I was going to post a screenshot to show what I mean but the question is closed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In which case it's up to Rick to edit this question to indicate why it's not a duplicate. I couldn't reproduce this margin either.